# Как изменить цвет рамки UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)didTouchAnswerButton:(id)sender {
  if([self.textField.text length] == 0) {
      self.textField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
  } else {
      // Вместо greyColor поставишь цвет своего филда когда он в нормальном состоянии
      self.textField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor greyColor]CGColor];
      //... Остальная логика
  }
}
```

А там где вы создаете текстовое поле вставьте

```
self.textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
self.textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
```

UPD:
Убрать подсветку через 10 секунд

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.textField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor greyColor]CGColor];
});
```

Comment: `textfield.text.length` - text пропустили

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, да точно, спасибо

Comment: Цвет не меняется.

Comment: на самом деле border не задан. надо добавить `self.textfield.layer.borderWidth = 1;` и чтобы скруглить углы `self.textfield.layer.cornerRadius = 5;`

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, спасибо, предполагал что он сам так делает при инициализации, а у него скорее всего просто RoundedRect textField